# big O in Growth of Functions

Tags: algorithm

Suppose we have two algorithms, *A* and *B*, for solving some problem (say multiplying two *n × n* matrices, or sorting an array n of integers). Let *n* denote the input size of the problem, and let *T<sub>A</sub>(n)* and *T<sub>B</sub>(n)* denote the number of steps
taken by algorithms *A* and *B*, respectively, on inputs of size *n*.
It is known that *T<sub>A</sub>(n) = O(n<sup>3</sup>)* and *T<sub>B</sub>(n) = O(n<sup>5</sup>)*. Is it true that for sufficiently large *n*, algorithm *A* performs less steps than algorithm *B*? Why or why not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I suppose you meant that the bounds are *O(n<sup>3</sup>)* and *O(n<sup>5</sup>)* (i.e., powers of 3 and 5, respectively).

Since [*O* is an upper bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), you can't really say anything about the comparisons. For example:

- *n<sup>2</sup> = O(n<sup>3</sup>)*, and *n<sup>1.5</sup> = O(n<sup>5</sup>)*, but, even for large *n*, the former function is larger than the latter.
- Conversely, *n<sup>1.5</sup> = O(n<sup>3</sup>)*, and *n<sup>2</sup> = O(n<sup>5</sup>)*, and here, for large *n*, the former function is indeed larger than the latter.

If the question would be about *Θ*, not *O*, the answer would be different - in that case, you *could* state that, for large enough *n*, the former performs less steps than the latter.

Comment: Why isn't it simply `n^3 < n^5`? when n is positive?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen That's the thing - it's not *&Theta;*, but *O*. So the question is why isn't something bounded above by *n^3* less than something bounded above by *n^5*, and there are counterexamples to that. I tried to explicitly state the difference to *&Theta;* in the answer, BTW.